# Bootstrap 2 Column Layout- Unequal Post size fix

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have created an app in ruby on rails and am using bootstrap ,i am using a 2 column layout ,the problem is the post sizes are unequal and an awkward gap ensues which i want to get rid of.

What my index page currently looks like:[image: Current Index Page]
What i want my index page to look like:[image: Desired Index Page]

my index.html.erb

```
   <div class="container">
      <% @posts.each_slice(2) do |posts| %>
        <div class="posts-wrapper row">
           <% posts.each do |post| %>
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-offset-1">
                <%= post.body %>
             </div> 
           <% end %>
        </div> 
      <% end %>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `.row` out of the loop and it will be fixed

or try the following code this should also work

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="posts-wrapper row">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <%= post.body %>
      </div> 
    <% end %>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have used [JQuery Masonry Library](https://masonry.desandro.com/)